# OS X remote kernel debugging, invalid thread when stepping through instruction

Tags: macos, debugging, lldb

A note:

I'm working on reverse engineering a certain OS X driver dependent on physical hardware, so a VM environment just won't do.

In my environment I have 2x 2015 Macbook Pro's running OS X 10.11.6 (15G18013) and have installed the latest KDK on both. To perform the remote debugging I setup network debugging over Ethernet using a Thunderbolt NIC on the second machine.

I have `lldb` working for the most part. I can set breakpoints, resume the kernel and breakpoint just fine, but the problem is after some time of doing `ni` (next instruction) I get the error `error: invalid thread`, and I can't send anymore commands to the other machine. When in this state the machine is still frozen (since I was stepping over instructions) and I can't seem to reattach to the other machine either, even after doing an NMI.

Comment: So you are saying for example `thread backtrace`,`thread list`, etc. don't work and you are unable to reload the kernel extension?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Setting up an exception breakpoint so that you aren't frozen when the thread disappears is probably how to handle it. It's not easy to kill a kernel extension once it's running, especially if the client debugger has already quit. Does `process interrupt`, `detach`, or `kdp-remote <machine or ip>` do anything either? I assume you have to manually kill the remote process...

Comment: > Does process interrupt, detach, or kdp-remote <machine or ip> do anything either? I assume you have to manually kill the remote process. 

Unfortunately, that is the situation. none of those commands seem to work in this state.

Answer (score 0):

The latest KDK for 10.11.6 is 15G17023. You can downgrade or wait for apple to release 15G18013. 
I have the same problem if I want to test the latest updates from apple with a kext.